# Deployment: Payload Error

Tags: deployment

Occasionally, when we queue deployments, we get the following error:

> The changes you requested require salesforce.com to temporarily lock your organization's administration setup. However, the administration setup has already been locked by another change. Please wait for the previous action to finish, then try again later.

I understand that this means that the previous deployment has locked the org, but the initial deployment has finished and the next deployment should be queued to deploy after. Presumably when the org is unlocked? It doesn't seem to want to wait for this change though.

I can simply wait a few minutes and re-deploy, but queuing deployments is really handy. Might anyone know what we can do to avoid this whilst queuing deployments? Or what the cause might be?

Couldn't find a lot of information for the error: `Payload Error`!

Comment: I have been seeing the same error this week when attempting to deploy updated case assignment rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this when deploying Profiles and Permission Sets. Thus makes sense to me a but since a Profile touches almost everything in an Org and the deployment Org needs to validate every reference.

Try keeping all your profile metadata aside and deploy them finally. That should make a difference.

Good luck.

Sridhar